# display new added custom tab in magento product page if data found

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, catalog, products, product-page

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>upsell_tabbed</alias><title>additional products</title><block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block><template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template></action>
```

- i have created a custom tab on product detail page and load all upsell
  products of current product in that tab.
- but now i want that tab will display only when    there is any
  product otherwise it should not display on the product    page.

  any help would be appreciated. thanx.

Answer (score 0):

- Find and open the tabs.phtml file. you can find it here:
- app/design/frontend/[YOUR PACKAGE]/[YOUR
  THEME]/template/catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml

Now get the total number of upsell products for the current product

```
$product_id = Mage::registry("current_product")->getId();
$_product = $object->load($product_id);
$upsell_count = count($_product->getUpSellProductIds());
```

NOW FIND THIS LINES OF CODE

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
            <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
                <li id="tab_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo ($i==0)?' active first':''?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

AND REPLACE IT WITH THIS CODE

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
            <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])):
                if($_tab['alias'] == 'youe_newly_created_tab_id' && ($upsell_count > 0))
                { ?>
                        <li id="tab_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo ($i==0)?' active first':''?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
        <?php   }           
                elseif($_tab['alias'] == 'youe_newly_created_tab_id' && ($upsell_count == 0))
                {
                        echo "";                      
                }
                else
                {  ?>                   
                        <li id="tab_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo ($i==0)?' active first':''?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
        <?php   }              

                 $i++; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

AFTER REPLACING CODE IT WILL HIDE YOUR TAB IF UPSELL PRODUCTS IS NOT THERE

[image]

AND FOR TAB CONTENT (BELOW TAB TITLE) APPLY SAME CODITIONS WHERE TAB CONTENT ARE CREATED

[image]

### NOTE: i know this is not a proper solution but it solved my issue

Answer (score -2):

Find and open the attributes.phtml file. This file can be found here: `/app/design/frontend/[YOUR PACKAGE]/[YOUR THEME]/template/catalog/product/view/attribute.phtml`

Open the file and search for the following lines:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Replace the entire foreach loop with the following lines of code:

<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?> 
    <?php if ((string)$_data['value'] != '' and $_data['value'] != 'N/A' and $_data['value'] != 'No'): ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="label" style="width:25%;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td><?php }?>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I think this answer has nothing to do with the question. The question is related to custom(upsell products) tab and your code is related to additional info tab.